# Thoughts regarding possibly dependent tags

Tags: discussion, tags

If I wanted to ask a question about [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash), should I also add the tag [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell)? Similarly, if I were to ask a question about [gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnome), should I also add the tag [desktop-environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-environment)?

Comment: I thought I killed the `desktop-environment` tag... if I let it live I wonder why... I always tag shell because I figure there might be people watching that. but I doubt anyone watches `desktop-environment`

Comment: @xeno The DE tag is still relevant. Look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/how-to-get-rid-of-desktop-environment-and-use-a-window-manager-only), [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/the-most-light-weight-compiz-compatible-environment), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/what-are-the-user-interface-subsystems-their-components-and-responsibilities) and [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/how-to-find-information-about-the-system-machine-in-unix).

Comment: that's probably why I didn't kill it. I recall at least thinking about it once... I think this tag has the potential to be abused because people might confuse its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on whether you think the answers are going to be specific to the most restrictive tag or not.

As an asker, you're often not expected to know, because it would take broad expertise of the subject. If you hover the mouse over a tag or click on it, you'll see a link to the tag wiki, which might contain helpful information. If in doubt, go with the specific tag (e.g., `bash`, `gnome`, `ubuntu`).

As an answerer, if you see a question that has a specific tag, and you know your answer *and most other likely answers* make sense in a more general setting, add the more general tag to your answer (e.g., `shell`, `window-manager`, `linux`). (Or, in the same vein, remove a `linux` tag if you know the question has inherently portable answers.)